# Convert std::vector<uint8_t> to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qimage

I am trying to create QImage from std::vector. I tried;

```
void FaceCutThread::convertImage(std::vector<uint8_t> &buf)
{
    QImage img(&buf[0], 300, 300, QImage::Format_ARGB32);

    emit isFinisedFaceCut(img);
}
```

and

```
void FaceCutThread::convertImage(std::vector<uint8_t> &buf)
{
    QImage img(buf.data(), 300, 300, QImage::Format_ARGB32);

    emit isFinisedFaceCut(img);
}
```

both two type of convertion didn't give any error;however, when I tried to show it in `QLabel` like;

```
void MainWindow::handleFaceResults(QImage& buf)
{
    QImage myImage(buf);
    ui->lblRawImage->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
}
```

my app always unexpectedly finishing. Could you please help how I can convert to QImage correctly?

EDIT:

I can write image into file without any problem like;

```
bool save_file (const string &path, const vector<uint8_t> &data)
{
    std::ofstream os;
    os.open(path.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if (!os.is_open())
        return false;

    os.write((const char*)data.data(), data.size());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that buf contains enough elements (300*300*4)?

Comment: @marom, actually I dont know buf's height and width... But I know its size. Please see my latest edit..

Comment: Ok, I reformulate my question: Is data.size (buf.size()) large enough? Should be (at least) 300*300*4.

Comment: @marom, as it's coming from SDK... I dont know, so let assume that it is not. How can I make it dynamic, without defining exact height and width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved a similar problem with [QImageReader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html) and [QBuffer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuffer.html)

```
QByteArray data = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buf.data()), buf.size());
QBuffer buffer(data);
QImageReader reader(&buffer);
QImage img = reader.read();
```

Comment: good for you,  however it is better to give an idea or your approach to understand more clearly..

Comment: The problem here is that the buffer must have some portable image format, like PNG or JPEG etc. If the buffer contains raw data, this is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the `std::vector<uint8_t> &buf` holds enough data for the picture. For QImage::Format_ARGB32 I would expect that 4 bytes are required per sample, so buf.size() must be at least 300*300*4.

What to do it it's less? Well, in that case probably the size of the image is not 300x300 and you need to figure out how to discover that. Or you can fill in buf with '0' to get the required size just to check that in that case everything works (or, better, nothing bad happens)

Comment: I change width and height to 50px. so in your example I need 10000 buf size. Where selecting image has 367974 buf size... But its again unexpectedly finished

Comment: Another thing I nortice is that you emit the signal and handle an object by reference (QImage &buf) when thge original has gone out of scope. What if you try to pass QImage by pointer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
QImage img;
img.loadFromData(buf.data(), buf.size());
img.scaled(QSize(300,300), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
...
```